# has_many association, store multiple associations in one column

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have two tables, `users` and `roles`. What I am trying to do is to create simple association between them, that `users` can have multiple `roles`.

In database it should look like that:

*Role*:

```
 id | name
-----------
  1 | ADMIN
  2 | USER
```

*User*

```
id | email         | username | roles
-------------------------------------
 1  test@gmail.com    test      [1,2]
```

So far, I came with following code:

```
def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :email, :string
      add :username, :string
      add :roles, references(:roles)
    end
  end

schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :username, :string
    has_many :roles, TimesheetServer.Role

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
     struct
      |> cast(params, [:email, :username])
      |> validate_required([:email, :username])
  end

def change do
    create table(:roles) do
      add :name, :string
      timestamps()
    end
  end

schema "roles" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :users, TimesheetServer.User
    timestamps()
  end
```

Then I am trying to seed database like that:

```
User.changeset(
    %User{},%{email: "test@gmail.com", username: "test", roles: [
        %Role{name: "ADMIN"},
        %Role{name: "USER"}
    ]})

    |> Repo.insert
```

Unfortunately, that does not create list of roles in `user` table, and does not save roles in `roles` table.

Any help or tips will be much appreciated!

Comment: So, a user should have many roles and a role should have many users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the above relation has to be defined as `many_to_many`. To achieve that, there are actually two ways.

First one is to define role schema as `embedded_schema`, in that case it will be embedded inside the parent (user). That means no db table will be created for role schema.

Second option is to join them through association table. That can look as follows:

*migration:*

```
def change do
 create table(:users) do
   add :email, :string
   add :username, :string
 end

 create table(:roles) do
   add :name, :string, null: false
 end

 create table(:users_roles, primary_key: false) do
  add :user_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)
  add :role_id, references(:roles, on_delete: :delete_all)
 end

 create unique_index(:users_roles, [:user_id, :role_id])
end
```

*user schema:*

```
 schema "users" do
  field :email, :string
  field :username, :string
  many_to_many :roles, TimesheetServer.Role, join_through: "users_roles"
 end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
   struct
    |> cast(params, [:email, :username])
    |> validate_required([:email, :username])
  end
end
```

*role schema:*

```
   schema "roles" do
     field :name, :string
     many_to_many :users, TimesheetServer.User, join_through: "users_roles"
   end

   def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
     struct
     |> cast(params, [:name])
     |> validate_required([:name])
   end
```

Now the association can be build in following way:

```
    user = Repo.get!(User, user_id) |> Repo.preload(:roles)
    role = Repo.get!(Role, role_id)

    user_changeset = Changeset.change(user)
                         |> Changeset.put_assoc(:roles, [role | user.roles])
```

That will result in having three tables:

*User:*

```
id | email         | username |
-------------------------------
 1  test@gmail.com    test
```

*Role:*

```
 id | name
-----------
  1 | ADMIN
  2 | USER
```

*users_roles:*

```
user_id | role_id
------------------
      1 | 1
------------------
      1 | 2
```